# Does Bootstrap 4.3.1 modal dialog have a data attribute similar to the jQuery UI data storage attribute?

Tags: jquery, datatables, bootstrap-modal, jquery-ui-dialog, laravel-6

So I'm trying to create CRUD functionality using the bootstrap 4.3.1 modal dialog.

And I was wondering if the boostrap modal dialog had a data storage attribute similar to that of the data storage attribute of the jQuery UI dialog?

What I'm trying to accomplish is something similar to the below jQuery UI dialog example:

```
$( "#create-country" ).button().click(function() {
    $( "#country-dialog" ).data("country_id", 0).dialog( "open" );
});

$( "#country-dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: "auto",
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Save": function() {
            var isValid = $("#country-form").valid();
            
            if ( isValid ) {
                save_country( $(this).data("country_id" ) );
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    close: function() {
    }
});

oCountryTable = $( "#country-table" ).dataTable({
    ajax: "{{ url( 'auth/country/get-countries' ) }}"
    ,columns: [
        {
            ....
            data:   "country_id",
            render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                if ( type === 'display' ) {
                    return "<a onclick=\"open_country_dialog('" + data + "');\">Edit</a>";
                }
                return data;
            },
            className: "dt-body-center"
        }
    ]
    ,"pagingType": "full_numbers"
    ,processing: true
    ,serverSide: true
    ,stateSave: true
});
```

I've already completed the CRD functionality for the bootstrap modal dialog.

However I was struggling to complete the U functionality of CRUD as I don't want to ad the key as a hidden element as shown below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="area_id" id="area_id">
```

and in the exaple here: https://www.techiediaries.com/laravel-6-ajax-crud-tutorial-with-bootstrap-modal-and-pagination-example/

Cheers,
Tim